# subsetting duplicates per individual

Tags: r, dplyr

```
dfin <- 
STUDY ID   CYCLE   TIME    VALUE
  1    1     0       10      50
  1    1     0       20      20
  1    2     1       20       20
```

Per study and ID, for those who have duplicate `CYCLE == 0` values, remove the row that had the higher `TIME`.

```
   dfout <- 
STUDY ID   CYCLE   TIME    VALUE
  1    1    0       10      50
  1    2    1       20       20
```

Using RStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to do a group by 'STUDY', 'ID' and `filter` out the `duplicated` 0 values in 'CYCLE'

```
library(dplyr)
dfin %>%
    arrange(STUDY, ID, TIME) %>%
    group_by(STUDY, ID)  %>%
    filter(!(duplicated(CYCLE) &  CYCLE == 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   STUDY, ID [2]
#  STUDY    ID CYCLE  TIME VALUE
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     0    10    50
#2     1     2     1    20    20
```

---

Also, if there are many duplicates for 0 and want to remove only the row where 'TIME' is also `max`

```
dfin %>% 
    group_by(STUDY, ID) %>% 
    filter(!(TIME == max(TIME) & CYCLE == 0))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
dfin1 <- do.call(order, dfin[c("STUDY", "ID", "TIME")])
dfin1[!(duplicated(dfin1[1:3]) & duplicated(dfin1$CYCLE)),]
#   STUDY ID CYCLE TIME VALUE
#1     1  1     0   10    50
#3     1  2     1   20    20
```

#### data

```
dfin <- structure(list(STUDY = c(1L, 1L, 1L), ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L), CYCLE = c(0L, 
0L, 1L), TIME = c(10L, 20L, 20L), VALUE = c(50L, 20L, 20L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: but this will remove the 2nd duplicate regardless but `TIME` is not sorted in my data frame, for example, if you swap `20` and `10` in the `TIME` column in first and second row, output will be different as in this case it will remove the 2nd row that has 10 in it.

Comment: @Amer In that case, just add an `arrange` before the `filter`

Comment: @Amer If you have 3 or more duplicate 0's per group, do you remove only the one wheere TIME is max

Comment: no I would remove all but the one that has min (TIME)

Comment: @Amer In that case, the first option and the `base R` should work